# Sphinx latexpdf works for others but not me

Tags: latex, python-sphinx

I'm on a small team using Sphinx for documentation. Others on my team are able to build the documentation fine using `make latexpdf`, but my build fails,

```
Running Sphinx v1.8.3
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [latex]: all documents
updating environment: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
looking for now-outdated files... none found
processing pti_cs_lectures.tex...index introduction arrays-arraylists numbering-systems
resolving references...
writing... done
copying images... [ 25%] images/z1.jpg
copying images... [ 50%] images/hardware.png
copying images... [ 75%] images/supercomputer.jpg
copying images... [100%] images/survey.png

copying TeX support files...
done
build succeeded.

The LaTeX files are in build/latex.
Run 'make' in that directory to run these through (pdf)latex
(use `make latexpdf' here to do that automatically).
latexmk -pdf -dvi- -ps-  'pti_cs_lectures.tex'
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./pti_cs_lectures.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(./sphinxmanual.cls
Document Class: sphinxmanual 2018/12/22 v1.8.3 Document class (Sphinx manual)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cmap/cmap.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)<<t1.cmap>>)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/times.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fncychap/fncychap.sty)
(./sphinx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabulary/tabulary.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty)
(./sphinxmulticell.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/makeidx.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix
<2008/02/07> (tvz)) (./footnotehyper-sphinx.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/parskip/parskip.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/alltt.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/capt-of/capt-of.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/needspace/needspace.sty)
(./sphinxhighlight.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/hypcap.sty)
Writing index file pti_cs_lectures.idx
(./pti_cs_lectures.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1ptm.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./pti_cs_lectures.out) (./pti_cs_lectures.out)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1phv.fd)<<ot1.cmap>><<oml
.cmap>><<oms.cmap>><<omx.cmap>>
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) [1{/usr/local/t
exlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

Package Fancyhdr Warning: \fancyfoot's `E' option without twoside option is use
less on input line 65.

(./pti_cs_lectures.toc)

Package Fancyhdr Warning: \fancyfoot's `E' option without twoside option is use
less on input line 66.

[1]

Package Fancyhdr Warning: \fancyfoot's `E' option without twoside option is use
less on input line 67.


Package Fancyhdr Warning: \fancyfoot's `E' option without twoside option is use
less on input line 67.


Package Fancyhdr Warning: \fancyhead's `E' option without twoside option is use
less on input line 67.

Chapter 1.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ts1ptm.fd)

Package Fancyhdr Warning: \fancyfoot's `E' option without twoside option is use
less on input line 139.

[1] (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1pcr.fd) [2 <./z1.jpg
>] [3] [4 <./hardware.png>] [5 <./supercomputer.jpg>] [6] [7 <./survey.png>]
[8] [9]
Chapter 2.

Package Fancyhdr Warning: \fancyfoot's `E' option without twoside option is use
less on input line 573.

[10] [11] [12] [13]
Chapter 3.

LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `numbering-systems:radix-decomposition' on page
14 undefined on input line 780.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `numbering-systems:binary-numbers' on page 14 un
defined on input line 783.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `numbering-systems:binary-arithmetic' on page 14
 undefined on input line 786.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `numbering-systems:binary-to-decimal-conversion'
 on page 14 undefined on input line 789.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `numbering-systems:decimal-to-binary-conversion'
 on page 14 undefined on input line 792.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `numbering-systems:conclusion' on page 14 undefi
ned on input line 795.


Package Fancyhdr Warning: \fancyfoot's `E' option without twoside option is use
less on input line 831.

[14]
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> }$\hfill \endtemplate

l.837 ... \times 10^1 & + 4 \times 10^0\end{split}

?
! Emergency stop.
<template> }$\hfill \endtemplate

l.837 ... \times 10^1 & + 4 \times 10^0\end{split}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

What could explain the discrepancy? I also do not know how to directly fix the latex error because it's generated latex.

Comment: You seem to have a large number of Sphinx-relatex local files in your working folder: `sphinxmanual.cls`, `sphinx.sty`, `sphinxmulticell.sty`, `footnotehyper-sphinx.sty`, `sphinxhighlight.sty`. There are [newer versions available](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/tree/master/sphinx/texinputs). Perhaps their versions differ from yours. Alternatively, supply a minimal document that we can use to replicate the issue (your `pti_cs_lectures` with only the error parts lines 800-900 so it's still functioning).